# Display a string over a polygon.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, wpf-controls

How do I put a string inside of a polygon? It will be is displayed in a [MapOverlay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.mapoverlay%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

```
private void DrawMapMarker(GeoCoordinate coordinate, Color color, MapLayer mapLayer)
{
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
    polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 75));
    polygon.Points.Add(new Point(25, 0));
    polygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    polygon.DataContext = "HIIIIIII";

    // Enable marker to be tapped for location information
    polygon.Tag = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
    polygon.MouseLeftButtonUp += polygon_MouseLeftButtonUp;

    // Create a MapOverlay and add marker.
    MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay();
    overlay.Content = polygon;
    overlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
    overlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0);
    mapLayer.Add(overlay);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use some kind of panel (eg, StackPanel), and put your polygon and a TextBlock in it:

```
private void DrawMapMarker(GeoCoordinate coordinate, Color color, MapLayer mapLayer)
{
    var content = new Grid { Width = 25, Height = 75 };

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
    polygon.Points.Add(new Point(0, 75));
    polygon.Points.Add(new Point(25, 0));
    polygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);

    var text = new TextBlock 
    { 
        Text = "HIIIIIII",
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange),
    };
    var viewbox = new Viewbox { Child = text };
    content.Children.Add(polygon);
    content.Children.Add(viewbox);

    // Enable marker to be tapped for location information
    polygon.Tag = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
    polygon.MouseLeftButtonUp += polygon_MouseLeftButtonUp;

    // Create a MapOverlay and add marker.
    MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay();
    overlay.Content = content;
    overlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
    overlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0);
    mapLayer.Add(overlay);
}
```

Comment: some how works but i need text to be inside the polygon and with different color

Comment: @user2918388 in that case, use a grid, and set the TextBlock's Foreground (edited above)

Comment: works fine thank you can the text fit the polygon width and height only

Comment: @user2918388 actually, you probably have to set a fixed size for the Grid.  I'm not too familiar with how Viewbox works.